# How to show only the active computers in a listview?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

I have a `ListView` called `lvInformation` and I want to add only the active computers in a remote network. But it will take many seconds when I get a response if it's active. I want this multithreaded, it should add a computer to the `ListView` when it's active and refresh the `ListView`. But I don't know how. I'm using the following code and that's working too but takes many seconds...

```
    System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping objping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();
    objping.SendAsync(_remoteComputerName, null);

    objping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(objping_PingCompleted);;
```

---

```
    private void objping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        DomainComputers.Add(_remoteComputerName);
    }
```

`DomainComputers` is a property and that's binded TwoWay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<string> DomainComputers = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        lvInformation.ItemsSource = DomainComputers;

        List<string> Computers = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 255; i++)
        {
            Computers.Add("192.168.9." + i.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var comp in Computers)
        {
            System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping objping = new System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping();

            objping.PingCompleted += new PingCompletedEventHandler(objping_PingCompleted);

            objping.SendAsync(comp, comp);
        }


    }

    void objping_PingCompleted(object sender, PingCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
            DomainComputers.Add(e.UserState as string);
    }
}
```

And in XAML

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListView Name="lvInformation" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Start" />
</StackPanel>
```

But take it as sample. I'm creatinig far to many Ping objects. In real life I will create array of 10 and in PingCompleted event I will use them to ping another computer in the queue.

Comment: I'm using a `ViewModel`, an error on the Dispatcher. `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method or property 'System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])'`

Comment: Remove Dispatcher, it is not needed. I have also add condition to check that ping was OK